# Doctrine - Query throw three Entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, associations, entity

i am dealing with a small problem in Doctrine2:

I have three Entities:

Article, SpecialArticle, SpecialArticleComponent

SpecialArticle:

```
class SpecialArticle extends ModelEntity {

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Article
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="articleID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $article;

    /**
     * INVERSE SIDE
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SpecialArticleComponent", mappedBy="specialarticle")
     */
    private $components;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->components = new ArrayCollection();

    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId() {

        return $this->id;

    }

    /**
     * Get article
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function getArticle() {

        return $this->article;

    }

    /**
     * Get components
     *
     * @return SpecialArticleComponent
     */
    public function getComponents() {

        return $this->components;

    }
}
```

SpecialArticleComponent

```
class SpecialArticleComponent extends ModelEntity {

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $specialArticleId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="specialArticleID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $specialArticleId;

    /**
     * @var integer $articleId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="articleID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $articleId; 

    /**
     * @var SpecialArticle
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SpecialArticle", inversedBy="components")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="specialArticleID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $specialarticle;

    /**
     * @var
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Article")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="articleID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $article;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId() {

        return $this->id;

    }

    /**
     * Get specialArticleId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getSpecialArticleId() {

        return $this->specialArticleId;

    }

    /**
     * Get articleID
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getArticleId() {

        return $this->articleId;

    }

    /**
     * Get article
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function getArticle() {

        return $this->article;

    }

}
```

When i want to get the "Article" and the "SpecialArticleComponents" throw the "SpecialArticle", it works this way:

```
$builder->select('specialarticle', 'article', 'components')
        ->from('SpecialArticle', 'specialarticle')
        ->leftJoin('specialarticle.article', 'article')
        ->leftJoin('specialarticle.components', 'components')
```

But when i want to use the "OneToOne"-assoiation to get the "Article" throw the "SpecialArticleComponent", than it fails:

```
$builder->select('specialarticle', 'article', 'components', 'componentarticle')
        ->from('SpecialArticle', 'specialarticle')
        ->leftJoin('specialarticle.article', 'article')
        ->leftJoin('specialarticle.components', 'components')
        ->leftJoin('components.article', 'componentarticle')
```

EDIT (complete error message):

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message 'SELECT specialarticle, article, o, mac, ca FROM SpecialArticle specialarticle LEFT JOIN specialarticle.article article LEFT JOIN specialarticle.components components LEFT JOIN components.article componentarticle in
```

Anybody knows why i cant use my OneToOne-assoziation declared in my "SpecialArticleComponent" ?

Thanks and Greetings

Comment: Please add the message of QueryException.

Comment: i updated, can you refer to it?

Comment: I would suggest you to remove FK to other entities defined as columns. It's not recommended and it can easily lead to confusion and problems in the future.

Comment: thanks for answering, but what do you mean by "FK" ?

Comment: FK - foreign key, you should not define column SpecialArticleComponent::specialArticleId because you already have a asociation SpecialArticleComponent::specialArticle